# Dynamics CRM 2011 notifications disappear

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

Is it normal that the notification area (fixed Yellow part at the top of the form) disappear after I change a field value?
I noticed it only disappears when I change the value of a lookup or date/time field, but not when I change text field.
Is there a way to keep the notification area visible until I want?

Answer (score 0):

The notification area is supposed to warn(/notify) you of a number of different conditions.  For example, one of the common ones I see is that "At least one of the recipients is not configured to receive emails" - shows on the email record.  It is there to tell you to either not send the current email to the selected user, or fix their user profile so they can receive emails.

To answer your question specifically around changing when this displays, you will probably need to create your own notification (because the OOB ones handle for themselves when they display or hide)
You can customize this area (in an unsupported way): here is how to hide the area:

```
 var notificationsArea = document.getElementById('crmNotifications');('crmNotifications');
    if (notificationsArea) {
        //Hide message
        notificationsArea.SetVisible(false);
    }
```

if you want to display a new item, you can probably just do a

```
/*
The integer is the notification type
1 = Error
2 = Warning
3 = Info
notificationsArea.AddNotification("<;unique value>;", 3, "","Your text here");
*/
/*Create some notifications*/
notificationsArea.AddNotification("1", 1, "1","Test 1");
notificationsArea.AddNotification("2", 2, "2","Test 2");
notificationsArea.AddNotification("3", 3, "3","Test 3");
```

If you have upgraded to CRM 2013/2015, good news is that this is now supported: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327828(v=crm.6).aspx#BKMK_setFormNotification